# SVG clip-path not working - multiple svgs on same page

Tags: svg, clip-path

I have multiple svgs on one page and have exported them individually from illustrator. I also passed them through omgsvg which reduced the file size.

However, when I view the complete page with all of my separate svgs inserted (via my server side html rendering engine), many of the clip paths don't seem to be functioning. Some do and some don't, I can't work out why.

Svgomg helped but didn't solve the problem entirely.  Some paths still don't function.

But all the clip paths work fine when loaded one at a time as individual svgs directly in chrome, or in the illustration program!  They only fail when put together in the html page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The cause of this problem is that during svg export, clip paths will be defined using standardised ids, chosen by your illustration program.  If you export several files, each of these files may well use the same id names.  Svgomg just uses letters, a,b...   Illustrator uses SVGID_1_, ...

What you need to remember is the role of ids on an html page.

Ids must be unique.  Clip paths are failing to work because you have the same id defined more than once when you insert multiple individually exported files.  The solution is to think of your html page as a whole, and make sure your ids across all images you will have on a page will be unique.